# If I switch to Ubuntu on a mid-2014 Macbook Pro (with integrated graphics) will I lose graphics performance?

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel-graphics, macbook

I've read elsewhere that Windows doesn't support the Intel integrated [graphics](https://www.lwks.com/index.php?option=com_kunena&func=view&catid=29&id=99627&Itemid=81). I'm curious if the performance of the system will decrease in this area if I switch to Linux? The integrated graphics card is 'Intel Iris Pro 1536 MB'. Thanks.

Comment: https://www.lwks.com/index.php?option=com_kunena&func=view&catid=21&id=155577&Itemid=81

Comment: Intel plays nice with Linux, so unless Apple has done something, it should work right out of the box without you having to find drivers.

Comment: Related: [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [intel webside](https://01.org/search/node/Intel%20Iris%20Pro%20type%3Aotcorg_download), intel did make drivers for Intel iris graphics so there should not be any noticeable performance lose.